# Reflection in Portable class library

Tags: reflection, portable-class-library

I want to dynamically load a dll in a portable class library. A code equivalent to that posted below. "AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName" does not seem to be supported in a portable class library. I need an equivalent code to the below that loads assembly based on name and path. I do not know the name of the assembly at compile time.

```
    public static object GetAssembly(string assemblyPath, string typeName)
    {
        AssemblyName assamblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assemblyPath);
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assamblyName);
        Type type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
        object instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        return instanceOfMyType;
    }
```

Comment: Please note that different platforms use different file path conventions, so it makes no sense in a portable class library to obtain the assembly (name) via the file path to the assembly. `Assembly.Load(AssemblyName)` is also not included in PCL, except in *Universal* libraries. I think that your best bet is to use `Assembly.Load(string)` and specify the full name of the assembly (which I guess means that it has to be available in the GAC.)

Comment: BTW, which PCL profile are you targeting?

Comment: Thanks, I believe there is no other option but to add the reference to the assembly. The profile was targeting Windows 8, Phone 8.1 and Windows Silverlight. My app is built for iOS devices where the PCL will be used.